# magento2 how to set a loder widget on a page load event

Tags: magento2.3.2, loader

i Want to set loader on **page load event**

how can do this any idea about that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please upload your code.

Comment: @RohanHapani i have searching it  but not found and always showing in ajax loader event

Answer (score 0):

You can use by simply way using jQuery script :

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';
        $(window).on('load', function(){
            $('body').trigger('processStart');
            $('body').trigger('processStop');
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can stop by below code on base of your requirement :

```
$('body').trigger('processStop');
```

> For UI Component :

```
require(['uiRegistry'], function (uiRegistry) {
    uiRegistry.get("customer_form.customer_form_data_source", function (element) {
        $('body').trigger('processStop'); // It will stop after ui component loaded
    })
})
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replay i want to on page load loader widget start and after page reloading finish then stop loader

Comment: Yes. I added code. You want to show loader like mentioned in screenshot right?

Comment: yes correct and stop it when is page reload finishing

Comment: You can add stop code after start code. Both will be trigger at there.

Comment: can you upadte code ? i have no idea about that so :)

Comment: Check my update please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101695/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'loader'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('body').trigger('processStart');
        }, 500);
        $(window).on('load', function(){
            console.log("page is loaded.");
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $('body').trigger('processStop');
            }, 500);
            console.log("Stop the Loader.");
        });

    });
</script>
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: working your code but loader not showing up https://prnt.sc/q4ys83
i have use in category page

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: same issue not showing loader

Comment: I have tested this code in dashboard, it's working fine. in which file you are adding this code?

Comment: i have use in category page